# Error handing using create! method in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with rails4. In my controller i have parsing json and storing into database.
My controller is like this,

```
def store
  @data.each do |invite|
     MemberInvitation.create!(:email => invite['email'])
  end
end
```

This works fine....

As we know `create will automatically call validators` but If the validation fails how to display the error messages using json render. Because i am defining validations in MemberInvitation model.

How to handle this scenario!!!

I wanted to render error messages in json format if error raised!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to get a report is:

```
def store
  errors = []
  @data.each do |invite|
     new_member = MemberInvitation.new(:email => invite['email'])
     errors.push(new_member) unless new_member.save
  end
  if errors.empty?
    #everything went fine
  else
    # you have all members with issues in the array
    # I advise you to create your json yourself
  end
end
```

Comment: Bur create storing last email in the database without giving any error message!!! Where it should show error message instead of storing into database!!!

Comment: keep cool. whats the problem? you dont want any member persisted if ever there is one single error?

Comment: @RubyOnRails new will only initiate an object, nothing is saved to db yet at that line

Comment: @apneadiving Sorry, after your editing the answer it works fine!!! Thanks for faster replay....